# Why does this Tikz tower look OK standalone but not when included as a figure in article?

Tags: tikz-pgf, input, standalone

I built two towers in Tikz. Because the document they will be included in takes a while to compile and because my Tikz skills are somewhat limited (so I need to compile often to check if I've done something crazy), I used `standalone` while working on the figure.

Here is a minimised version of the towers with colouring and labelling removed:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    rounded corners=1pt,
    node distance=0pt,
    rock/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=5mm, minimum height=5mm, outer sep=0pt},
    rock1/.append style={rock, minimum width=10mm},
    rock2/.append style={rock, minimum width=15mm},
    rock3/.append style={rock, minimum width=2.5mm, minimum height=10mm, yshift=2.5mm},
    rock4/.append style={rock, minimum width=12.5mm},
    rock5/.append style={rock, minimum height=10mm, yshift=2.5mm},
    rock6/.append style={rock, minimum width=2.5mm},
    rock7/.append style={rock, minimum width=7.5mm, minimum height=10mm, yshift=2.5mm},
    rock8/.append style={rock, minimum width=2.5mm, minimum height=15mm, yshift=5mm},
    rock9/.append style={rock, minimum width=7.5mm},
    key/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=2.5mm, minimum height=2.5mm},
    keytxt/.style={font=\sffamily},
  ]

    \node (rbase1) [rock1] {};
    \node (rbase2) [rock2, base right=of rbase1] {};
    \node (rbase3) [rock3, base right=of rbase2] {};
    \node (rbase4) [rock4, base right=of rbase3, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (rbase5) [rock5, base right=of rbase4] {};
    \node (rbase6) [rock, base right=of rbase5, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (r1r4) [rock6, left=of rbase3, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r1r3) [rock5, left=of r1r4] {};
    \node (r1r2) [rock1, left=of r1r3, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (r1r1) [rock, left=of r1r2] {};
    \node (r1r5) [rock1, right=of rbase3, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r1r6) [rock3, right=of r1r5] {};
    \node (r2r1) [rock4, left=of r1r3, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r2r2) [rock, right=of r1r3, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r2r3) [rock5, right=of r2r2] {};
    \node (r2r2) [rock, right=of r2r3, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (r3r1) [rock1, above=of r2r1, xshift=1.25mm] {};
    \node (r3r2) [rock7, right=of r3r1] {};
    \node (r3r3) [rock8, right=of r3r2, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (r3r4) [rock, right=of r2r3, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r4r1) [rock, above=of r3r1] {};
    \node (r4r2) [rock, right=of r4r1, rock3] {};
    \node (r4r3) [rock9, right=of r3r3] {};
    \node (r5r1) [rock6, above=of r4r1, xshift=1.25mm] {};
    \node (r5r2) [rock3, right=of r4r2, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r5r3) [rock3, right=of r5r2, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (r5r4) [rock6, right=of r5r3, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (r5r5) [rock5, right=of r3r3, yshift=5mm] {};
    \node (r6r1) [rock3, left=of r5r2, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r6r2) [rock5, right=of r5r3, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r7r1) [rock5, right=of r6r1, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r7r2) [rock3, right=of r6r2, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r8r1) [rock3, right=of r7r1, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r8r2) [rock3, right=of r8r1, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (r9r1) [rock6, left=of r8r1, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (r10r1) [rock, above=of r8r1] {};
    \node (r11r1) [rock6, above=of r10r1] {};

    \node (ebase1) [rock, right=of rbase6, xshift=30mm] {};
    \node (ebase2) [rock5, base right=of ebase1] {};
    \node (ebase3) [rock1, base right=of ebase2, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (ebase4) [rock6, base right=of ebase3] {};
    \node (ebase5) [rock3, base right=of ebase4] {};
    \node (ebase6) [rock1, base right=of ebase5, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (ebase7) [rock2, base right=of ebase6] {};
    \node (e1e1) [rock3, right=of ebase2, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (e1e2) [rock1, right=of e1e1, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (e1e3) [rock6, right=of ebase5, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (e1e4) [rock3, right=of e1e3] {};
    \node (e1e5) [rock3, right=of e1e4, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (e1e6) [rock, right=of e1e5, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (e1e7) [rock1, right=of e1e6] {};
    \node (e2e1) [rock5, right=of e1e1, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (e2e2) [rock1, right=of e2e1, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (e2e3) [rock9, right=of e1e5, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (e2e4) [rock, right=of e2e3] {};
    \node (e3e1) [rock, right=of e2e1, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (e3e2) [rock8, right=of e3e1] {};
    \node (e3e3) [rock7, right=of e3e2, yshift=-5mm] {};
    \node (e3e4) [rock1, right=of e3e3, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (e4e1) [rock9, left=of e3e2] {};
    \node (e4e2) [rock6, right=of e3e3, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (e4e3) [rock, right=of e4e2] {};
    \node (e5e2) [rock3, left=of e3e2, yshift=5mm] {};
    \node (e5e1) [rock3, left=of e5e2, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (e5e3) [rock6, right=of e3e2, yshift=5mm] {};
    \node (e5e4) [rock5, right=of e5e3] {};
    \node (e5e5) [rock, right=of e5e4, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (e6e1) [rock, right=of e5e2, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (e6e2) [rock3, right=of e5e4, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (e7e3) [rock3, left=of e6e2, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (e7e2) [rock3, left=of e7e3, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (e7e1) [rock9, left=of e7e2, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (e8e2) [rock5, left=of e7e2, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (e8e1) [rock6, left=of e8e2, yshift=-2.5mm] {};
    \node (e9e1) [rock6, right=of e8e2, yshift=2.5mm] {};
    \node (e10e1) [rock, above=of e8e2, xshift=1.25mm] {};
    \node (e11e1) [rock6, above=of e10e1] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I finally got the output to look reasonable:

[image: standalone towers]

The next step was to include the figure in the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \input{standalone-tower}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, now the towers do not look quite right:

[image: input towers]

I can (and have) tweaked the left hand tower to make it look more-or-less OK but neither tower looks as good as it did standalone.

I have two questions:

1. What causes the misalignment when the code is `\input` but not when compiled standalone?
2. How could or should I have gone about constructing the original towers to ensure that they would give the same results when compiled in the main document as when compiled standalone?

Comment: You are using different font sizes: in standalone \normalfont has size 10pt, in your article you are using 12pt.

Comment: You may add `inner sep=0` as global option of your `tikzpicture` (its default value is `.3333em` that depends on current font size).

Comment: If you have your figure done with `standalone` you can also include it as `pdf` with `includegraphics`.

Comment: So the font size matters because it affects `inner sep`? I would have thought of font size had there been any text in the image or had I specified dimensions in terms which depend on font size. But that didn't occur to me in this case. I assume `0pt` is the same regardless and the `1pt` only affects the corners, not the overall size. Thanks. @PaulGaborit do you want to write an answer? Ulrike Fischer's comment wouldn't have meant anything to me even though I understand the point now I've got your comment. (I knew I had different font sizes but couldn't see why that would matter here.)

Comment: @Ignasi I know but for complex reasons to do with difficulties printing in colour if I do that, I'd rather minimise the number of things I include as separate files. Included PDFs are unavoidable, unfortunately, but they are a great deal of trouble and I'd prefer to minimise the complications.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Setting `inner sep` works beautifully. I reverted my tweaks, applied yours and it all works beautifully again! Thanks.

Comment: subversion is so useful...

Comment: For anyone visiting from the future, the comment by @UlrikeFischer works perfectly still so just modify one of your documents to use the other font. Thank you a lot, very useful information.

Comment: @JamesT Yes, but you might want to use the same image in a Beamer presentation and a handout, say, but not be forced to use the same font size. This isn't a criticism of UlrikeFischer's comment. That comment doesn't prescribe changing one of the document's sizes. The `inner sep` solution is equally compatible with UF's diagnosis. I just didn't understand it at the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your picture depends implicitly on the size of the current font... via the default value of `inner sep` (`.3333em`). In your standalone figure, the current size is 10pt. In your document, the current size is 12pt.

You may add `inner sep=0` to the global options of your `tikzpicture` for breaking this dependency.